# R looping: to display numbers in an interval

Tags: r, loops, count, range, intervals

I have a dataset and I want to display the numbers for each row between col1 and col2 counted by col3 using R:

```
dataset=data.frame(col1=c(3,9,15), col2=c(4,11,16), col3=c(2,3,2))
```

My result should look like:

```
3
3
4
4
9
9
9
10
10
10
11
11
11
15
15
16
16
```

Seems trivial but I cannot get a for loop work. Thanks.

Comment: `unlist(Map('rep', Map(\`:\`, dataset[, 1], dataset[, 2]), each = dataset[, 3]))`

Comment: Thanks rawr. This line of code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
col1=c(3,9,15)
col2=c(4,11,16)
col3=c(2,3,2)
res = NULL
for (k in 1:length(col1)){
    res = c(res, sort(rep(col1[k]:col2[k],col3[k])))
}
```

Result:

```
> res
 [1]  3  3  4  4  9  9  9 10 10 10 11 11 11 15 15 16 16
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

Or this can be done with `apply`

```
unlist(apply(dataset, 1, function(x) rep(x[1]:x[2], 
       each=x[3])))
#[1]  3  3  4  4  9  9  9 10 10 10 11 11 11 15 15 16 16
```

Comment: @Nanuk No problem.  Glad to help you.